# Command reacts on second click/tap

Tags: .net, wpf, mvvm, data-binding, uwp

I'm still learning MVVM, using INotifyPropertyChanged and ICommand, so sorry if this is something obvious.

I have a `SimpleCommand` class which inherits `ICommand`

```
class SimpleCommand : ICommand
{
    private Action _action;
    #region ICommand
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }
    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        this._action();
    }
    #endregion
    public SimpleCommand(Action action)
    {
        _action = action;
    }
}
```

And I'm when a user calls:

```
<Button Command="{Binding ChangePaneOpen }" .../>
```

A variable PaneOpen should be changed:

```
public bool PaneOpen
{
    get { return _paneOpen; }
    set
    {
        _paneOpen = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("PaneOpen");
    }
}

public ICommand ChangePaneOpen
{
    get
    {
        return new SimpleCommand(() => { PaneOpen = !PaneOpen; });
    }
}
```

which changes the binded value:

```
<SplitView IsPaneOpen="{Binding PaneOpen, Mode=OneWay}" ...>
    ....
</SplitView>
```

But, for some reason, only every second click (except the very first time I click the button) is being reacted to. It's not a double click, since I can have a big pause between the clicks.

What am I doing wrong here?

If you need any more info about the code, ask me and I'll try to provide!

**EDIT:** Closing the `SplitView` is always done by a single click (so `PaneOpen = false` always reacts correctly, weirdly enough, but opening `SplitView` always requires a double click/tap (except the very first time I click on the button))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was 99% correct, I will explain what happens.

1.- When you tap the button you pass PaneOpen from false to true. (right)

2.- When you tap out of the pane after is opened, the pane closes but it does not update PaneOpen to false, because you set the binding in Mode=OneWay, you have to set Mode=TwoWay to make the binding bidirectional and set PaneOpen to false again.

With that you have your code perfect.

Comment: Yep, that did it. I understand what I did wrong, thank you very much!